# U and Me (this is not a dating puzzle)

Tags: reverse-puzzling

> U and me together!

> Me after: double!

> U are three times greater than me!

> U too will be removed!

**What is the puzzle that is similar to the sentences given above?**

Hint 1:

> Me = I

Comment: It's definitely three times, and not two?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This looks like it is the

> [MU puzzle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MU_puzzle)

where

> Each line represents one of the transformation rules.
>  'U' corresponds to **U**, 'me' to **I** and 'Me' to **M**

U and me together!

> We can add a **U** to the end of any string ending in **I**

Me after: double!

> We can double any string after **M**

U are three times greater than me!

> We can replace any **III** with **U**

U too will be removed!

> We can remove any occurrence of **UU**

Comment: Sorry for not accepting for 10 days